# Capturing JS errors in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm capturing js errors in the application with `window.onerror`, but the thing is - in Chrome if dev tools isn't opened - then the `url` parameter passed to `onerror` handler always equals to the opened url.

While if dev tools is opened - then the `url` points to the exact `.js` file the caused the js error.

How do you deal with it? Are there any workarounds?

And to be more clear - here are 2 results:

1. `Uncaught ReferenceError: a is not defined index:122` - this was received after fetching a page
2. `Uncaught ReferenceError: a is not defined List.js:122` - this was received after fetching the same page with dev tools opened. This is an expected result - I've put `a();` call to the `List.js` file for testing.

**UPD**: this is done for functional testing (using selenium webdriver) - I want to capture js errors for further investigations.

Comment: If you're looking for an exception that needs to be fixed, I'd say to open the dev tools' Sources tab and then use the "Pause on all/uncaught exceptions" in the bottom left of the panel.

Comment: @Fabrício Matté: it's for functional testing - I'd like to capture js errors for further investigation. Sorry I didn't mention it initially

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's pose the following architecture:

```
window.addEventListener("error", handleException, false);

function handleException(I_sMsg) {

    if (I_sMsg.stack) {
            sMsg = I_sMsg.stack.replaceAll(getBaseURL(), "");
        alert(sMsg);
    } else if (I_sMsg.message) {
        alert(I_sMsg.message);
    }   

    return cancelEvent(I_sMsg);
}
```

Now any `throw new Error("description");` will go through the first part of the if statement and have a nice stack for you to parse with the urls.

It also works for unexpected exceptions, having as a result the following message (in this case after calling the unexisting `bibi()` function)

[image: screenshot of an unexpected exception]

After further investigation, my framework is using some kind of home made job management (as shown in the stack actually) where every single action belongs to a job.

The job execution method is the following (simplified)

```
    try {
        oTask.func.apply(oTask.obj, oTask.prms);
    } catch(ex) {
        handleException(ex);
        return false;
    }
```

So it means every single execution is encapsulated within this single try catch block. As you see, the **exception** is caught, and passed to the handler. Not the **error**.

I though it was working in the other file but it was because the call was encapsulated, while within the api.js file directly it was a free call not managed by the framework.

Comment: It's not actually about application level error handling, but about unexpected js errors, like calling non-functions or accessing properties of undefined variables.

Comment: yes, it works as well. I'm going to add a screenshot in 2 minutes

Comment: that would be nice, since for my example with calling non existing `a()` function it doesn't give anything new

Comment: edited. Please note you don't see the full URL because the handleException I am using truncates it. But you have the full URI which is I believe what you asked for.

Comment: Are you sure you've provided the exact code? I don't even see where `sMsg` is defined

Comment: But anyway - there is no `.stack` property in `I_sMsg` object here Version 26.0.1410.43 m

Comment: I am using this since chrome 15 or 16, and it works. This is rather odd. My version now is 27.xxx beta but it does not matter I think. Let me think.-

Comment: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/4486681/stack.png --- here is a complete object's structure

Comment: oh oh, interesting. I found what I think is the problem. You know this is my personal API and it works very well. But I have a slightly more complex architecture behind: an api.js file containing the error management, and some other js files. When I try `bibi();` in the api.js file, I have the same result as yours. But when I try it from another js file, it works as shown in my screenshot. Interesting enough, when the error comes from the api.js file BUT belongs to a stack starting from another file, the result is good too! So that's the starting point that matters,

Comment: it appears that it does not work well when it is within the js file where the error handler is defined.

Comment: They are in different. The handler is defined right in html, and the error is triggered in a separated file, hmmmm

Comment: After moving to a completely separated file - nothing changed, hmhmhm

Comment: From what I've found on MDN - it only should work with custom thrown exceptions. And now reading https://code.google.com/p/v8/wiki/JavaScriptStackTraceApi

Comment: Yep, perhaps for the testing purposes I'll wrap my application entry point with a `try-catch`. Though I'm sure it won't help with asynchronous operations, but still better than nothing

Comment: Yes, for the async operations I also made a specific manager which handles this situation. ;)

Answer (score 1):

More of a *something to try* answer really but it might help.

Chrome recently added `chrome://inspect/` to the list of handy URLs (see `chrome://chrome-urls/` for the complete list). I cannot find the tweet or blog post I read about this unfortunately but I think it was within the last month. The URL works on Chrome 28 for sure.

`chrome://inspect/` lists all open tabs with an **inspect** link which redirects back to the existing open page but also opens DevTools.

I'm thinking that the selenium test could open the site under test in one tab and in a second tab open the *inspect* page, follow the `inspect` link back to the test page but this time with DevTools open, allowing `window.onerror` to capture better errors.

Something like:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('row')[n].getElementsByTagName('a')[0].click()
```

Comment: "and in a second tab open the inspect page" --- I'm not sure, but if it could - then this might be a solution, thanks :-)